# Include a bin file in firebase functions

Tags: c++, firebase, function, storage, bin

I have a firebase project which includes the firebase functions feature. In one of the functions, I need to include a bin file (compiled from a C++ source) which will be used to run a command inside the function, something like:

```
./bin_file_name param1 param2 param3
```

I tried to put the bin file inside the functions/ directory and deployed the functions using

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

But the bin file does not get uploaded (or at least I think that is the case) because the response is that the bin file was not found.

How do I do this? Is it possible to include a bin file in firebase functions? Or should I just try to upload the bin file in firebase storage and access the bin file from there? Any help is appreciated and if you need me to include the actual code please let me know.

Comment: Tried using a relative path? `./bin_file_name param1 param2 param3`

Comment: Yes. I tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked if the target file was uploaded from the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser)? Functions will be deployed under a entry here prefixed with `gcf-sources`.